# Is it possible to get the text from a text cell with a code cell in google colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I'm trying to make a word counter of my text cells. My idea was to somehow get the text from the text cells and then work the strings. I would like to know if it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, here's an example:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1dxq_K3vgIYjxDL7DpxoHRfJEQbxThM57

[image]

The three cells do three things:

1. Authenticate for access to Drive.
2. Download the JSON content of the notebook.
3. Count the words for the markdown cells in the notebook.